# "For whom the Bell tolls" vs "who this book is for"

Tags: sentence-structure

Why is there the difference between those structures? Why not "who the bell tolls for" or not "for whom this book is", for instance?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is entirely in register.

*For whom the bell tolls* and *Who the bell tolls for*  are precisely equivalent in meaning. The difference is that the first is more formal or literary (and, as others have said, is a quotation).

(*For who the bell tolls* and *whom the bell tolls for* are also both possible, but less likely, because they show a mixed register: people who use *whom* tend not to like ending with the stranded *for* and vice versa).

*Who the book is for* is a slightly different case because the verb is *is*, and I find *For whom the book is* a bit odd. But if it were *For whom the book is intended* = *Who the book is intended for* that would be fine either way.

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you!

Comment: I don't think "for who the bell tolls" is too great.

Comment: I don't think it's that great either, but it does occur. The GloWbE corpus has 71 instances of _for who the_ against 706 of _for whom the_ (once I've eliminated all the _for whom the bell_).

Answer (score 1):

For whom the bell tolls: after a preposition, you need the objective sense.

Who this book is for remains a mystery.: who is a subject

[who versus whom from Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/who-vs-whom-grammar-usage)

> What to Know
> Who performs the action of a verb (e.g. “Who sent us this
> gift?“), while whom receives the action (“We got this gift from
> whom?“). In grammar terms, that makes who a subject, and whom an
> object. When following a preposition, whom is the preferred choice
> (“To whom should we address our thank you note?“).

Comment: Should I not send to know for whom the book is?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Please stop. That sentence you wrote does not make much sense. That said, you wrote "for whom" which I already explained.

Comment: I was harking back in an oblique way to the Donne poem that started all this (Check it out). Just being light-hearted. Sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 1):

First, “For whom the bell tolls” is a quotation from an early 17th century work by John Donne. English was more heavily inflected then. Here is another quotation from the same author

> If thou be’st born to see strange sights,
> Things invisible to see,
> Ride ten thousand days and nights,
> Til age snow white hair on thee

If you use his locutions in 21st century America, people  will think you are from another planet. English has changed since the 17th century.

Second, many people still inflect “who.” Many people still inflect pronouns that are objects of prepositions.

> The car honked at him

is correct.

> The car honked at he.

is just wrong. That is why what is correct is

> For whom the bell tolled

just as it would be

> It was for him that the bell tolled

**EDIT**: My quotations from Donne are by memory. They may be off by a word or two.

Furthermore, the clause “for whom the bell tolls” is a dependent clause in a longer sentence in a full paragraph, which ends “it tolls for thee.”

Once again, the object of the pronoun “for” uses the objective case of “thou,” namely “thee.”

**EDIT 2**: I have seen Colin Fine’s answer and agree that everyone will take the same meaning from “For whom the bell tolls” and “Who the bell tolls for.” I do not agree that that they represent a mere difference in register. For me, the second is a mark of someone who is either careless or unskilled in English.

Comment: Does anybody ever say **The car honked at he?**

Comment: @RonaldSole  People, even supposedly literate people, do say things like “between him and I.” In any case, I was trying to make it clear that, in received English, pronouns that are the object of a preposition are in the objective case through an extreme example. Are extreme examples another violation of the rules of this site?

Comment: @JeffMorrow All examples should reflect correct and current usage, unless otherwise marked. People do say "between him and I", but it's not considered correct. Nobody says, "The car honked at he". Incorrect grammar is not the same as an "extreme example". It seems better to prefer standard idiomatic examples over extreme examples anyway.

Comment: @gotube I have changed my wording.

Comment: My friend Mary Ellen in Chicago (in 21st century Illinois, America), won't think such a speaker is 'from another planet'; she'll think they are well-read. And so will her students.